# Newline from file being read as char in c program

Tags: c, file, scanf, newline, delimiter

I'm reading for a csv file so each element is separated by commas. I'm using a comma character as the delimiter except for the last element which I use the newline character for. The issue is that the newline character is now being read into the first element of the next node.

```
fscanf(file,"%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],% 
[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^\n]",
                            newnode->id,
                            newnode->name,
                            newnode->sex,
                            newnode->age,
                            newnode->height,
                            newnode->weight,
                            newnode->team,
                            newnode->noc,
                            newnode->games,
                            newnode->year,
                            newnode->season,
                            newnode->city,
                            newnode->sport,
                            newnode->event,
                            newnode->medal);
```

So the first node would be fine, but the seconds one's id would be:

ID: \n249655

for example.

Comment: Why is that surprising? You never read the newline character.

Comment: The issue is that it is reading the newline character. The newline character from the previous line is being read as part of the next nodes ID string.

Comment: yes, clearly. If you had wanted to read the newline when you read the rest of the line, you would have put something like `%*1[\n]` at the end of the format, right? But you didn't, so the character was still there to be read by the next scanf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use library functions like `fscanf` to read CSV files since just delimiting by commas doesn't account for quoted strings with commas inside them. If you know that you're only working with CSV files that don't have quoted strings, then you're good.

If you prepend the format string to `scanf` family functions with a space then any whitespace characters at the beginning of the input are ignored:

```
" %[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^\n]"
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you used `fgets` + `sscanf` combination. `fgets` read a line to a buffer, while `sscanf` will parse this line. This will avoid buffer overflow vulnerability on your code, and also will fix your error.

Here is a full example that reads 3 integer delimited by commas from standard input.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static char buffer[BUFSIZ];

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int a,b,c;
    while (fgets(buffer, BUFSIZ, stdin) != NULL) {
        sscanf(buffer, "%d,%d,%d", &a, &b, &c);
        printf("%d, %d, %d\n", a, b, c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```